# Pandas dataframe a particular case of merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I merge the rows of the *dataframe1* into the *dataframe2* ?

- If one of the corresponding values is NaN then the value should be
  copied from the other.
- If both are NaN then NaN.
- If none are NaN then the first one.

**Dataframe1**
[image: Dataframe1]

**Dataframe2**
[image: Dataframe2]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post data in text as opposed to images.  It makes answering and viewing easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df
Out: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   NaN   NaN   3.0     4
1   1.0   2.0   NaN     5

df.loc[0].combine_first(df.loc[1])
Out: 
col1    1.0
col2    2.0
col3    3.0
col4    4.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

In the specified format:

```
df.loc[0].combine_first(df.loc[1]).to_frame('Row1-2').T
Out: 
        col1  col2  col3  col4
Row1-2   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
```

An alternative:

```
df.loc[[0]].fillna(df.loc[1])
Out: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   2.0   3.0     4
```

And a cleaner version of filling from @MaxU:

```
df.bfill().iloc[[0]]
Out: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   2.0   3.0     4
```

Comment: I think `df.bfill().iloc[[0]]` would be a bit more generic ;-)

Comment: @MaxU Yes that's much clearer. You should post it as an answer! :)

Comment: no, i will not post it as an answer as it's just a slightly modified version of your answer :)